Is Tucker Carlson "accepting money from the Russian government"?
In a Q&A session following a talk on geopolitics, Peter Zeihan (a well-known geopolitical analyst and author) claims that Tucker Carlson is being paid by Russia to push its agenda, as he answers a question from a member of the audience about Tucker's recent interview with Putin.
Here's the interaction:

Peter: "[Tucker Carlson]'s been a Russian shill for about 8 years"
Audience member: "Can you describe that?"
Peter: "He's been accepting money from the Russian government to push
the Russian position in western media for 8 years"

Source: End of the World Q&A - Marietta College - Peter Zeihan - March 27, 2024 (6:12)
Is there any evidence for or against this claim?

The claimant there has somewhat strange ideas about 'true' journalism in the sequent (around 10-15 mins in). Claims the only orgs that still send people on the ground are Al-Jazeera and France24. Ignores Reuters & AP etc.

Is this a notable claim?

@gerrit well Peter Zeihan is a well known figure in geopolitical analysis and the statement was made in a public forum and recorded / disseminated publicly. My understanding is that this would meet the standard for being notable.

@quant Sure!  Maybe you can add a small note to indicate that Peter Zeihan is well-known, as that would be enough to establish notability I think.

@gerrit good suggestion thanks

@gerrit: the video already has 1.2K likes and some 40K views. Granted, that's not the only topic it covers, but still.

Not evidence, but if Zeihan can't back up his claim then Carlson would seem to have good grounds for a libel suit.

@PaulJohnson: a suit may require discovery and that can backfire. https://www.salon.com/2023/04/14/he-cant-risk-discovery-experts-say-trumps-against-michael-cohen-could-badly-backfire/ ; https://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow-show/maddowblog/lawsuit-inadvertently-produces-new-details-post-2020-chicanery-rcna89708

@user253751: https://www.reuters.com/graphics/ISRAEL-LEBANON/JOURNALIST/akveabxrzvr/ Yes, they don't seem to send Westerners there, but hire locals. FWTW.

Maybe, impossible to know without audit of the man's financials.
Evidence in support:
Carlson's content is used verbatim by RT programs:

Russian news hosts take clips of Carlson’s shows and build their own segments around them, following his lead on topics and expanding on his narratives. In some ways perhaps it’s only the logical conclusion that one of them would eventually just cut out the middleman and make an entire show based around Carlson’s clips.

It is customary, in IP law, to pay the content creator for content uses in this way.
Carlson appears to be implicated in the Tenet Media charges, he isn't named per se but is identifiable from context.
Carlson gave an infamous 2-hour interview to Vladimir Putin, which all-but-certainly wasn't a pro-bono affair, though the extent to which the Kremlin or other Russian business interests actually funded the trip isn't clear.
All of the above is circumstantial, but the counter-evidence is even more so:
Russian entities aren't necessarily well incentivized to respect US IP laws.
It's not clear from the Tenet Media case that Carlson was aware of his likeness being used (even if he clearly hasn't objected to it).
TL;DR
It's not readily clear that Carlson actually gets funds directly from Russia, Russian Companies, or their agents.  It is, however, clear that he financially benefits from favorably speaking of Russian interests up to and including being granted access to Vladimir Putin, a privilege that distinguishes his product in the marketplace.
It would not be at all surprising, given the Tenet Media case, to discover that such funding was actually occurring - but Carlson is a private citizen and so his financials are not a matter of public record.
